# Use Case design. Reading with extends or have them Separate

Tags: uml

I am creating an android application and just designing a simple use case diagram. 
Quick question regarding the use case design, The user can read different sections on my app such as "about the app", "useful Links, "terms & conditions" etc.

Would it make more sense to have one use case "Reads" and add the above sections as an extension to the one use case?

Or as they are all different options the user can choose from, adding them all as separate use cases such as "reads about the app", "reads useful links"

I can include images if anyone is confused with the question.

Many thanks, Leon

Answer (score 0):

Just ask yourself: does it add value? A use case should be named with predicate-subject(-object) so `Read` is no valid name for a UC. What would be more appropriate? Probably `Inform user` (at a good guess). Now, is there any advantage in creating more and "finer grained" UCs? No, definitely not. Added value is a bigger chunk of the system. A user wants to see those added values in a block, not a lengthy list of "we offer this, and that, and ....".